# Is pgbarman 2.10+ with barman-cloud-* commands does not require a dedicated server for receiving wal log anymore?

Tags: backup, postgresql

With the latest release of pgbarman since 2.10, I saw there seems to be ways to setup the postgreSQL server to directly backup to S3 with the following tutorials:

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/barman-cloud-part-1-wal-archive/

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/barman-cloud-part-2-cloud-backup/

Is this technically means I don't need to install a barman server anymore? Whats the recommended setup? Or should I create both to ensure I have better RPO?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested barman and barman cloud today.
I setup barman on a dedicated server with wal streaming replication, it works so I would do the same setup with barman cloud but something went wrong, barman cloud doesnt find the pg_control file only present on the postgresql server.
I have posted an issue on barman project, ask them if barman cloud cannot be installed on remote server.
This will create over workload for postgresql server so I dont understand if barman cloud can only be installed on postgresql server ...
https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/barman/issues/326

best regards